# Branch Coverage and DU Paths

Tags: testing

Is there a situation where you can have 100% Branch Coverage and still have DU paths that have not been tested? If so, can I please have a simple example?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand definition-use paths correctly (for each set value there needs to be a tests that go to the points where the value is used), I think branch coverage doesn't guarantee this. Consider the following program:

```
z = "foo"

if x > 10:
    z = "bar"
else
    pass

if y > 5:
    print z
else
    pass
```

Now, if we test with (x = 0, y = 10) and (x = 20, y = 0), we cover all the branches. First test will evaluate false branch in the first if and true branch in the second if. Second test will evaluate true branch in the first if and false branch in the second if. All branches are covered, but there is no test where printing z would result in "bar".

Comment: ah yes, so it's an illegal use because it hasnt been defined yet. very nice example thank you.

Comment: z has been defined in the beginning of the code, but the value may change. The difference comes from the fact that selection of branches doesn't use all the defined variables.